# Questions about subquerying in mysql

Tags: mysql

First and foremost, this is part of an assignment, but I'm trying to get more clarification on how subquerying works in regards to the initial query.

The question is List the name of every student and SSN who earned an A in all courses he or she has completed, i.e. no Null grade and every grade is an A.

Am I correct in assuming that this can completed with a subquery? or should i be using some outer join method to combine students that only have A's in all courses.  I'm unsure as to which should be the nested query and the outside query.  I tried doing:

```
SELECT *
From Student S JOIN Enrollment E
WHERE S.SSN = E.SSN AND E.Grade = "A"
ORDER BY E.CourseNumber
```

as my nested query which will return all students that have A's but the question is asking which students have earned A's in all of their courses.  Not sure what I would make my outside query.  Using this requires me to put something as select since I obviously can't compare multiple variables to each other and I'm not sure what to compare there either.

Here's some context to the db's:

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
SSN INT(9),
Name VARCHAR(20),
Major VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY (SSN)
);

CREATE TABLE Course(
CourseNumber INT(5),
PrerequisiteCourseNumber INT(10),
CourseTitle VARCHAR(10),
NumberUnits INT(2),
PRIMARY KEY (CourseNumber)
);

CREATE TABLE Section(
CourseNumber INT(5),
Quarter VARCHAR(10),
RoomNumber INT(5),
DayTime VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (CourseNumber,Quarter),
FOREIGN KEY (CourseNumber) REFERENCES Course(CourseNumber)
);


CREATE TABLE Enrollment(
SSN INT(9),
CourseNumber INT(5),
Quarter VARCHAR(10),
Grade VARCHAR(1),
PRIMARY KEY (SSN,CourseNumber,Quarter),
FOREIGN KEY (SSN) REFERENCES Student(SSN),
FOREIGN KEY (CourseNumber) REFERENCES Course(CourseNumber),
FOREIGN KEY (Quarter) REFERENCES Section(Quarter)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
SSN INT(9),
Name VARCHAR(20),
Major VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY (SSN)
);

CREATE TABLE Enrollment(
SSN INT(9),
CourseNumber INT(5),
Quarter VARCHAR(10),
Grade VARCHAR(1),
PRIMARY KEY (SSN,CourseNumber,Quarter),
FOREIGN KEY (SSN) REFERENCES Student(SSN)
-- FOREIGN KEY (CourseNumber) REFERENCES Course(CourseNumber),
-- FOREIGN KEY (Quarter) REFERENCES Section(Quarter)
);

insert student(ssn,name,major) values
(1,'John','b'),(2,'Sally','b'),(3,'Kim','b'),(4,'Stan','b');

insert enrollment(ssn,coursenumber,quarter,grade) values
(1,1,'F2015','A'),
(2,1,'F2015','A'),(2,2,'F2015','B'),
(3,1,'F2015','B'),
(4,1,'F2015','A'),(4,2,'F2015',null),(4,3,'F2015','A');
```

### Query

```
select distinct s.ssn,s.name
from
(   select ssn,count(ssn) outCount
    from
    (   select e.ssn,e.grade,count(e.ssn) theCountInner
        from enrollment e
        where e.grade is not null
        group by e.ssn,e.grade
    ) xInner1
    -- where count(ssn)=1
    group by ssn
    having outCount=1
) xInner2
join student s
on s.ssn=xInner2.ssn
join enrollment
on enrollment.ssn=xInner2.ssn
and enrollment.grade='A'
+-----+------+
| ssn | name |
+-----+------+
|   1 | John |
|   4 | Stan |
+-----+------+
```

Note that the `distinct` is used to get rid of two rows for Stan that would result without it.

Note, `xInner1` derived table brings back grades without nulls with counts at the SSN level.

That is quickly recount for SSN's that with `having`=1. That becomes derived table `xInner2`.

That is joined back to student and enrollment finding an A. And as mentioned, `distinct` cleans it up so Stan does not appear twice.

I am sure there are other ways. That is my hack